# How do we split the columns in excet sheet into two columns based on the data present in the column?

Tags: excel, split

I have data in one column i.e., Purchases as

```
Purchases
2 Pens
3 Books
4 Pens
1 Gifts 
2 Books
```

I want to split it as

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
2Pens  3Books 1Gift
4Pens  2Books
```

Comment: Your title says two columns but the question body uses three?

Comment: Index() and match() can do this, many examples exist on here - some answered by me so I’m not writing another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel O365, you could use in `C1`:

```
=FILTER($A1:$A5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("* "&INDEX(UNIQUE(MID($A1:$A5,FIND(" ",$A1:$A5)+1,LEN($A1:$A5))),COLUMN(A1)),$A1:$A5)))
```

Drag the formula right.

[image]